# Winston logging. Roll over but keep same file name

Tags: winston

I am using winston for logging.

I have the log files roll over after a certain size. So they would look like 

myLog.log

MyLog1.log

But it starts using the myLog1 as the new log file. I want it to keep writing to myLog.log and have myLog1 as the old one. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a there is an option that can be used. tailable. If this option is set to true then it will work as described in the question.

```
    new winston.transports.File({
        filename: logLocation,
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: true,
        maxsize: 100000,
        maxFiles: 5,
        colorize: false,
        tailable: true
    }),
```

Answer (score -1):

It does not create new file after reaching maxsize

Comment: Interesting. The above example has a huge size though(100mb). It might be worth trying a smaller size to confirm.

So changing max size to something like this
'maxsize: 1000,'